# Replacing true/false/null in React Map render with strings "true/false/null"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say in React I am iterating over a return of JSON data in state `this.state.searchData` and some of the values that return contain `true` or `false` or `null` from the api call such as these:

```
   "active": true,
   "partition": null,
   "auth": false
```

For the map iteration below, how would I test for each of these values in the key/value and then replace them with the string "true", or "false" or "null" to show up in the render in browser?  Right now my code renders everything correctly until it encounters true, false or null in a value for the key and it just renders nothing/empty

```
{Object.entries(this.state.searchData).map(([key, value]) => (
  <ul>
    *** test key value here for null, false or true and output string "null, false or true"
    <li>{key} : {value}</li>
  </ul>
   )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the String object to get the string representation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

```
<li>{key} : {String(value)}</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

In React/JSX templating, boolean/null/undefined values wont render as they are used for conditional rendering as well.

**Reference**:
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored

But you can convert to string and render it?

```
<h1>{String(true)}</h1>
<h2>{String(false)}</h2>
<h2>{String(null)}</h2>
```

All the above will render as string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce`

```js
let data = {
  "active": true,
  "partition": null,
  "auth": false,
  "Valued": "MyValue"
};

let asTextData = Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
  let item = {}
  switch (value) {
    case null:
      item[key]="null";
      return {...result,...item}
    case true:
      item[key]="true";
      return {...result,...item} 
    case false:
      item[key]="false";
      return {...result,...item}
    default :
      item[key]=value;
      return {...result,...item}
  }
},{});

console.log(asTextData);
```

Also you can cast using `String()` but if you are use it in render time and you have other value types like integer or floats, may you need to convert them to number again.